# How can I change this line in order to eliminate for loop?

Tags: swift

I have the below line. `anyPosts` is of type `(key: String, value: AnyObject)`. This line however will only loop 1 time. So I would like to change it so that I can access `anyposts.key` withough using for loop.

Preferably I would like to only use 1 line. Like:

```
let anyPostKey = anyPosts as! [something...]
```

I have tried to find what to cast it to but I could not find anything.

```
for anyPosts in postDictionary {
```

Incase the info is relevant, `postDict` is of type: `[String : AnyObject]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `postDictionary` which you claim to have one key/value pair.

Your goal is to access that one key.

```
let anyPostKey = postDictionary.keys.first! // will crash if dictionary is empty
```

`anyPostKey` will be a `String` since `postDictionary` is defined as `[String: AnyObject]`.